# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

Here is my error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at TestGrades.setRaceTime(TestGrade.java:49)
    at GradeDriver.getGradeData(GradeDriver.java:40)
    at Grade Driver.main(GradeDriver.java:26)
```

Java-Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeDriver{
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] averageInfo = new double[3];

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] fileName = new String[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        fileName[i] = args[i];
    }

    Scanner input = getInputFile(console, fileName);
    PrintStream output = getOutputFile(console, fileName);

    TestGrades[] grades = getGradeData(input);
    showGradeInfo(output, grades);
    getAverageInfo(averageInfo, grades);
    showAverageInfo(output, averageInfo, grades[0]);

}

public static TestGrades[] getGradeData(Scanner input) {
    int numberOfGrades = input.nextInt();
    TestGrades[] grades = new TestGrades[numberOfGrades];

    for(int driver = 0; driver < numberOfGrades && input.hasNext(); driver++) {
        grades[driver] = new TestGrades(input.next(), input.next());
        for (int grade = 1; grade <= 4; grade++) {
            grades[driver].setRaceTime(grade , input.nextDouble());
        }
    }
    return grades;
}

public static void showGradeInfo (PrintStream output, TestGrades[] grades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        output.print(( i + 1 ) + ". " + grades[i] + "\n");
    }
}

public static void getAverageInfo (double[] info, TestGrades[] grades) {
    double low = 20.0;
    double high = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    double totalAverage = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        average = grades[i].getGradeAverage();
        if (average > high) {
            high = average;
        }
        if (average < low) {
            low = average;
        }
        totalAverage = totalAverage + average;
    }
    info[0] = low;
    info[1] = high;
    info[2] = totalAverage/grades[0].getCounter();
}

public static void showAverageInfo(PrintStream o, double[] info, TestGrades d) {
    String[] s = {"Total number of students: "};

    o.printf("\n%d. %s %d\n", 1, s[0], d.getCounter());
    for (int i = 1; i <info.length; i++) {
        o.printf("%d. %s %.2f/n", i + i, s[i], info[i - 1]);
    }
}
public static Scanner getInputFile(Scanner console, String[] inFileName) {
    boolean fileFound = false;
    Scanner s = null;
    if (inFileName[0] == null) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the input file name: ");
        inFileName[0] = console.nextLine();
    }

    do {
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File(inFileName[0]));
            fileFound = true;
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read file: " + e) ;
            System.out.println("Enter the correct input file name: ");
            inFileName[0] = console.nextLine();
        }
    }
    while (!fileFound);
        return s;
    }

public static PrintStream getOutputFile (Scanner console, String[] outFileName) {
    boolean fileFound = false;
    PrintStream pS = null;
    if (outFileName[1] == null) {
        System.out.print("Please enter output file name: ");
        outFileName[1] = console.nextLine();
    }
    do {
        try {
            pS = new PrintStream (new File (outFileName[1]));
            fileFound = true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {

            System.out.println("Cannot read file: " + e2);
            System.out.println("Enter a correct output file name: ");
            outFileName[1] = console.nextLine();
        }
    }
    while(!fileFound);
        return pS;
    }
}





import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestGrades {
private static int gradeCount = 0;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double[] raceTime = new double[4];

public TestGrades(String fName, String lName) {
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    gradeCount++;
}

private String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;

}

private String getLastName() {
    return lastName;

}

public double getGradeAverage() {
    double highest = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < raceTime.length; i++) {
        sum += raceTime[i];
        if (raceTime[i] > highest) {
            highest = raceTime[i];
        }
    }
    sum = sum - highest;
    sum = sum / 3;
    return sum;
}

public void setRaceTime(int grade, double time) {
    if (grade < 1 || grade > 4 || time < 0.0 || time > 15.0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    raceTime[grade - 1 ] = time;
}

public int getCounter() {
    return gradeCount;
}

public String toString() {
    return (firstName + " " + lastName);
}
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: not really making this easy on us... What file(name) is this you pasted here? What is at those lines in the stack trace? (I'm not going to count). What have you tried? Can you maybe remove the irrelevant code?

Comment: @ZachL It's Java so the filenames must be "GradeDriver.java" and "TestGrades.java" for the two classes posted. Really obvious when looking at the stacktrace, too. But I agree that I am missing some effort from the OP here, too.

Comment: yea, realized that shortly after posting the comment; suffice to I'm not a native Java speaker ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you threw the `IllegalArgumentException` yourself.

```
if (grade < 1 || grade > 4 || time < 0.0 || time > 15.0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

But you didn't supply a message as an argument to the constructor.  You should supply a message that will make more sense when displayed, for example:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("grade (" + grade + ") or time (" + time +
    ") outside of legal range.");
```

You are probably entering a `time` value outside of your range.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing the exception yourself...

```
if (grade < 1 || grade > 4 || time < 0.0 || time > 15.0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```